# Not able to establish database connection in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, db2, datasource, db2-luw

I want to make a new database connection (DB2) in eclipse for the purpose of using JPA. In JPA perspective, in `Data Source Explorer` view, when I try to create a new db connection, I receive the following logs when I try to ping the server.

```
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.exceptions.DBNotStartException: No start database command was issued. ErrorCode = -4499, SQLState = 08001.
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.internal.luw.JDBCLUWJDBCConnection.getConnectException(JDBCLUWJDBCConnection.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.getTestConnectionException(PingJob.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ro: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.8.87] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server example.example.com/51.37.93.117 on port 50,000 with message: Connection timed out: connect. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:319)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:337)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.zb.a(zb.java:378)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.zb.<init>(zb.java:76)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.y(a.java:306)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:1796)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.lb.a(lb.java:570)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.lb.<init>(lb.java:522)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:306)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:214)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.internal.luw.JDBCLUWConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCLUWConnectionFactory.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.run(ab.java:34)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.zb.a(zb.java:372)
    ... 18 more
```

And I am successfully able to connect to the database using [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Error opening socket to server {machine} on :

1. > port 60,000 with message: **Connection refused**. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
2. > port 50,000 with message: **Connection timed out**: connect. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

In the first one, connection refusal can be either 50,000 (port) or 60,000 (TCP/IP).

In your case, the problem can be caused possibly because:

1. There's another instance using the port (50,000 indicates not availability of db2)
2. Or the port has an issue (firewall blockage, wrong port number,..)

Check the library that you're using `import com.ibm.db2.jcc.*;` and set the right port setPortNumber(port). Use `Telnet 51.37.93.117 50000` in command line to check the availability of the port, if blank screen then the port is open else the port might be close/busy.

Use this [link here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014448340) to reference the steps you can take for db2 configuration in the `Data Source Explorer`on how to stop, set, update and start commands to re-connect to or to create a database.